# Mongoose find by ObjectID reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

I have two schemas:

```
    let adSchema = mongoose.Schema (
    {
        author: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        title: {type: String, required: true },
        town: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Town', required: true},
    }
);
```

And town schema:

```
    let townSchema = mongoose.Schema (
    {
        name: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
        ads: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ad'}]
    }
);
```

I need to make query that finds all Ads by `town.name`
How can I do that?

Comment: 1) You can use do it easily first query on townSchema with town name `find` and them get all ids of ads then query on adSchema.
2) You can use auto populate plugin `https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a town by name and use the mongoose populate method to fill the ads Array from town object.

You can find examples in the mongoose documentation:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Yes but i have also category reference in ads schema and author and i need to list them also.But i cant populate them if i search by Town - town name.

Comment: Ah, ok,  I didn't noticed that it's a reference. Taking into account that mongo it's a document oriented database, you can embed the ad schema inside the town schema if the relation it's one to few. Another option is to mantain the town name as metadata of ad. You can see the basic rules for mongo schema design here: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1